# sed: Why does command q add a new line?

Tags: sed, newline

Suppose the following command

```
echo -en "abc1\ndef2\nghi1" | sed -n 'p; d;'
```

In this case the output is just the same as it would be without sed at all. So the last line still has no new line character. Next command

```
echo -en "abc1\ndef2\nghi1" | sed -n '$! {p; d;}; /1$/ {s/1$//; p; d;}'
```

sed prints all but the last line without modification. The last line is shortened by one character. Still there is no new line character on the last line. Next command

```
echo -en "abc1\ndef2\nghi1" | sed -n '$! {p; d;}; /1$/ {s/1$//; p; q1;}'
```

("d" replaced by "q1" in the last command block. Same output as before, but this time there is an additional new line character in the last line.

- Why?
- How to fix?

(For those who are interested in the intention for this command: Given a certain STDIN, I want to scan for the last character, pass on STDIN to STDOUT without this last character and set an exit code based on that character. There should no other modification. sed seems to be perfect, if there wouldn't be this newline problem

```
sed -n '
  $! {p; d;};            #print any non last line, do next cycle
  /0$/ {s/0$//; p; d};   #last line ending with 0? Remove 0, print, next cycle
  /1$/ {s/1$//; p; d};   #last line ending with 1? Remove 1, print, next cycle
  {p}                    #fall back, print last line 
'
```

So far this script works perfect regarding to the newline issue. No new line is added. Now if i replace the "d" command  with "q"

```
sed -n '
  $! {p; d;};            #print any non last line, do next cycle
  /0$/ {s/0$//; p; q0};  #last line ending with 0? Remove 0, print, exit 0
  /1$/ {s/1$//; p; q1};  #last line ending with 1? Remove 1, print, exit 1
  {p}                    #fall back, print last line 
'
```

the newline problem suddenly arise...

Other solutions are welcome, they should be as fast as possible.

Comment: does the `q` cmd really accept an optional integer argument or is it just ignoring it? What happens if you change `q1` to just `q`? Well illustrated problem, good luck getting an answer!

Comment: yes, it does accept an optional integer. The integer is used as exit code. But some manpages do not specify this. "q" is just a shorthand for "q0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a bug. According to the manual, `q` should not print the pattern space if auto-print is disabled. Thus, it should not print anything. Since you are already using GNU `sed`, you could avoid this problem by using `Q` instead of `q`. At least, this works for me (version 4.2.2).

Comment: Yes, using "Q" instead of "q" solved the problem for me, too. Thanks a lot!